# Put an image as background in Fancytikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put an image as background using the Fancytikzposter. I used the background package, but, as expected, there is an incompatibility between the background predefined in fancytikzposter and the new I put. How can I solve that?, I need to modify fancytikzposter.sty, or is not really necessary?. This is what I have

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} % here most of the things are deﬁned
\usepackage[contents=Douhh,color=red]{background}


\usetemplate{3}


\setmargin{2} %margin width in cm
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
\setblockspacing{1.5} %distances between blocks in cm
\setheaddrawingheight{12} %height of header in cm
\setcolumnnumber{3}
\setblocktitleheight{4}


 \title{The Title}

 \author{Homer Simpson \\
 Institute for Nuclear Physics\\ 
 University of Springfield }



 \begin{document}

 \AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}
 \noindent
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \initializesizeandshifts
 \setyshift{10} % this makes space for the abstract box
 \titleblock{70}{1}

\blocknode{Block 1}{

  Some text here!

 }

 \startsecondcolumn

 \blocknode{Block 2}{
 Fill here
 }


 \startthirdcolumn

 \blocknode{Next block}{

  Fill here\dots

  }


 \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

I get as a result [image]

I want to put instead of the text an external image that fills all the white background. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node at(current page.center){\includegraphics{image}};}
```

at the end.

### Full Code

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} % here most of the things are deﬁned
% \usepackage[contents=Douhh,color=red]{background}

\usepackage{mwe} % provides the background image used in the example

\usetemplate{3}

\setmargin{2} %margin width in cm
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
\setblockspacing{1.5} %distances between blocks in cm
\setheaddrawingheight{12} %height of header in cm
\setcolumnnumber{3}
\setblocktitleheight{4}

\title{The Title}
\author{Homer Simpson \\
  Institute for Nuclear Physics\\ 
University of Springfield }

\begin{document}

% <other document contents>

\tikz[remember picture,overlay,opacity=.3]{
  \node at(current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}};
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]